# 'Range.Find' test for nothing says "Object Required"

Tags: excel, vba, search, find

Why do I get the error that an object is required if I run this piece of code?:

```
    Dim mitarbeiterStatus
    Dim mitarbeiterCell As Variant
    Set mitarbeiterCell = Nothing
    Dim rowsinWorkflow As Integer
    rowsinWorkflow = Worksheets("worksheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    With Worksheets("worksheet1").Range("B2:B" & rowsinWorkflow)
        Dim firstAddress
        mitarbeiterCell = .Find(displayName, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not mitarbeiterCell Is Nothing Then 'ERROR HERE
            firstAddress = mitarbeiterCell.Address
            Do
            '.....
            Set mitarbeiterCell = .FindNext(displayName)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And mitarbeiterCell.Address <> firstAddress
```

I tried doing it like here by the way: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff839746.aspx

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500") 
Set c = .Find(2, lookin:=xlValues) 
If Not c Is Nothing Then 
    firstAddress = c.Address 
    Do 
        c.Value = 5 
        Set c = .FindNext(c) 
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress 
End If 
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
mitarbeiterCell = .Find(displayName, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

To this:

```
Set mitarbeiterCell = .Find(displayName, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Comment: it may be worth it to declare `mitarbeiterCell` as a `Range` as well, so: `Dim mitarbeiterCell As Range`

Comment: You could, but nothing wrong with using a variant to hold the object.